# Was the Woocommerce Order API just changed recently? Attributes

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

We have a client who has problems importing orders from Woocommerce in their ERP system. And the data the API delivers does not match with I find in the documentation: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-properties

In the API at the customer, product attributes in order lines are in metadata:

```
      {
         "id":12619,
         "name":"XXXXX",
         "product_id":2373,
         "variation_id":0,
         "quantity":2,
         "tax_class":"",
         "subtotal":"2035.06",
         "subtotal_tax":"0.00",
         "total":"1882.43",
         "total_tax":"0.00",
         "taxes":[
            
         ],
         "meta_data":[
            {
               "id":152174,
               "key":"_bundled_items",
               "value":[
                  "93369e8dXXX8312fc7",
                  "5e5d733XXX5e5703dXX3182"
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":152176,
               "key":"_stamp",
               "value":{
                  "246":{
                     "product_id":940,
                     "quantity":5,
                     "attributes":{
                        "attribute_pa_languagevariant":"fr-en"
                     },
                     "variation_id":"941",
                     "discount":""
                  },
```

It is this attributes/attribute_pa_languagevariant that is causing problems. First, I do not see in the documentation at all how these attributes are handled.

Second is it possible they changed the API recently from pa_languagevariant to attribute_pa_languagevariant ?

As I see in legacy code referring to "pa_languagevariant" ?

Answer (score 0):

As I see from [Woocommerce REST API documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BisVP.png), there is a `meta_data` field on the line_item property when getting an order.

Is your question about how the product attributes work?

- You can find them under `Products > Attributes`.
- You can then use them on the product page. For a variable product, you can also use attributes to generate product variations.

[image]

Is the meta_data `_stamp` handled manually by you (code)? Or is it from Woocommerce or another plugin?